# How to write unit test in TypeScript for function inside function?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am using Angular 16  with the ngRx framework. I develop code using TypeScript. I have to face writing some unit tests (.spec.ts) using Jasmine, for code like the below. How can I call this method in the test class?

```
export function x1(p1: P1) {
  function xx1(
    tree: T<Code>[],
    code: T<Code>
  ): string | null {
    //some logic
    if(true){
      return "Message";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return xx1;
}
```

In test class

```
describe('P1', () => {
  const p1 = new P1();
  const validatorFn$ = x1(p1);

  it('should return true', () => {
    // Need to call methiod here
    

  });
});
```

Comment: What's the _problem_ with calling the function returned? Note the `$` suffix is usually used to indicate an _observable_.

Comment: xx1, need to call with it needed parameter.I tried but not succes

Comment: So give a [mre] of that. You evidently know how to call a function with parameters, what makes `validationFn$` any harder to call than `x1` was?

Comment: let r =validatorFn({ code} as unknown as T<Code>[],
      { code } as unknown as T<Code>) .thank you , i think this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call you validatorFn as any other function:

```js
const validatorFn = x1(p1);
var result = validatorFn(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Functions that returns function are called **Higher order functions**.
You can google that term: https://www.google.com/search?q=higher+order+function+testing&oq=higher+order+function+testing